# Failing to resolve dependencies with Cassandra for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt

I'm using spark-cassandra, with the following dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-core"  % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.0",
  "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3"
)
```

SBT fails to resolve dependencies. What should I change to make it work?

```
    Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.8 ...
...
    [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.0-M3: not found
    [error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.0-M3: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0-M3"`, as you are using scala 2.11, this should resolve it

[maven central repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.0.0-M3)

Comment: Alternatively, you can just add a double '%' in order to have the scala version appended in your ModuleID as in `"datastax" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3"`